# server overview page not displayed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

In eclipse after configured tomcat server,double click on server or right click on server and click open generally server Overview page was displayed.But this Overview page is not displayed.How to configure to display this page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to configure to open the server Overview page (editor). Try closing all open editors beforehand. Or restart eclipse.